# How to register SQL Server servers in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-express

I have some problems on how to register SQL Server servers in SQL Server Management Studio.

1. I Right clicked on `Local Server Groups` and select `New Server Registration`.

[image]

2. I named the `Server name` with `Myname\SQLEXPRESS` (`SQLEXPRESS` was the instance name)

[image: ![enter image description here]

3. I clicked `Test` , and got an error.

[image]

I thought the `Server name` was wrong. Can the `Sever name` be random ?

4.

[image]

If I named the `Server name` with `LAPTOP-F1RBQ6BK\SQLEXPRESS` , then I can `Test` successfully.
Did the `Sever name` must be `LAPTOP-F1RBQ6BK\SQLEXPRESS` ?

Comment: The server name is where the SQL Server instance is installed, which on a local system is the computer name. There is no such thing as a *random* server name, any more than there is a *random* IP address that will lead you to this site.

Comment: @Ken White When I named the `Server name` with an IP address such as `127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS` , there will also be a same error.

Comment: As I mentioned before, the name is set duruing **installation**, meaning when you install the SQL Server instance.

Comment: If `LAPTOP-F1RBQ6BK\SQLEXPRESS` works but `127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS` does not then either (1) SQL Server Express is not configured to listen with the TCP/IP protocol, or (2) Windows Firewall is "helping" by blocking the connection. For (1) open the SQL Configuration Manager that was installed with SQL Server/Express and check that the TCP/IP protocol is enabled on the Server Protocols, Client Protocols (32-bit) and Client Protocols (64-bit) tabs. For (2) open Windows Advanced Firewall and ensure that in Incoming Connections there is an Allow rule for SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Server Name` part must be the actual instance that you are connecting to, the `Registered Server Name` can be your own name for it.

In your initial part, where you have entered `MyName\SQLExpress` - it can't find the computer named `MyName` and so can't connect.

You need to enter the same connection name as you would if you connected directly using Object Explorer.  As @AlwaysLearning has mentioned the reason the IP Address is not working is likely to be that the instance is either not started or not listening on TCP/IP.  IIRC, by default for SQLExpress it will only be using Shared Memory so you will have to follow the approach to open SQL Configuration Manager and enable the additional protocol.   Check in the error log after restarting to ensure there is an entry for `listening on <your IP Address`.